# i want to select both matching and non matching both rows from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i have writen this query to select matching and non matching both rows from opening balance table and also from gernalledger table, but its only showing matching rows in two table,i want to select all the rows from openingbalance Table,`

```
SELECT   GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,CA.AccountName as AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Credit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningDebit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL 
Join ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id
Left Join OpeningBalance o on o.AccountId=CA.Id
Where CA.ClientId = 1

GROUP BY GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName
```

`[image: OpeningBalanceTable]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join for three tables and move CA.ClientId = 1 in On Clause instead of Where Clause

```
SELECT   GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,CA.AccountName as AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Credit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningDebit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL 
LEft Join ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id
Left Join OpeningBalance o on o.AccountId=CA.Id
and CA.ClientId = 1

GROUP BY GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName
```

Comment: I would move the check on `ClientId` to the first join, but otherwise I agree with this +1.

Comment: Still not getting  the balance of account id 94 in openingbalance table

Comment: could you please add some sample data in your question

Comment: @fa06 i already added the Openingbalance table , picture and output picture

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Full Outer Join OpeningBalance o on o.AccountId=CA.Id
```

Comment: still not getting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the data from both the tables, use FULL OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN in your query as below,

Also join OpeningBalance table on o.AccountId with GL.AccountId in GeneralLedgerLine table

```
SELECT   GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,CA.AccountName as AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Credit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningDebit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL 
Join ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id
FULL OUTER Join OpeningBalance o on o.AccountId=GL.AccountId
Where CA.ClientId = 1

GROUP BY GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName
```

If you want to select all the rows from OpeningBalance table but not all the rows from GeneralLedgerLine table, then use RIGHT OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN in your query,

Also join OpeningBalance table on o.AccountId with GL.AccountId in GeneralLedgerLine table

```
SELECT   GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,CA.AccountName as AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Credit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningDebit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL 
Join ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id
RIGHT OUTER Join OpeningBalance o on o.AccountId=GL.AccountId
Where CA.ClientId = 1

GROUP BY GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName
```